# Secret 3x3 square

Tags: mathematics

I have a 3x3 square filled with numbers. You can select a sub-rectangle^ and I will tell you the sum of all the numbers inside that rectangle. The penalty for doing this is $10-X$, where $X$ is the area of the selected sub-rectangle. How can you find all the numbers while incurring the smallest total penalty?

^ Note the sub-rectangle can be square.

Comment: Are the secret numbers unique, or can there be duplicates?

Comment: There can be duplicates. But if you have a nice solution that assumes uniqueness then please post it too!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the best penalty we can do is

> 41

Reasoning

> To determine nine unknown numbers requires nine linearly independent simultaneous equations, so I need to ask about nine sub-rectangles. The best way to optimize the penalty is then to pick the largest subrectangles I can and hope that the associated equations are linearly independent.
>  I can first pick the whole 3x3 square, then each of the four possible 2x3 (or 3x2) subrectangles, then each of the four possible 2x2 squares.
>  Luckily, Wolfram alpha tells me that the associated matrix for this linear system has non-zero determinant so this will allow me to compute all the numbers.
>  The total penalty is, therefore, $(10-9) + 4\cdot(10-6) + 4\cdot(10-4) = 41$

Comment: Very nice! Does this work in all cases, eg. if all numbers are 0?

Comment: It reminds me a bit of [Rubik's Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Clock).

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I think so yes, if all the sums are zero, it should correspond to all elements being zero and vice versa.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky For an explicit calculation, you can use $a = (abcdefghi-defghi)-(bcefhi-efhi)$ for a corner cell, and $b = (abdegh-degh)+(bcefhi-efhi)-(abcdefghi-defghi)$ for an edge cell, where the cells are labelled $a$ to $h$. The other corner and edge cells are found similarly by symmetry.

Comment: I came up with a solution with a larger penalty than hexomino so I was curious to see their solution. Turns out mine was the same! I think hexomino has made an error in the penalty calculation: >!the 2x2 rectangles should contribute a penalty of 6 (not 5). I would have made this a comment, but I have insufficient reputation.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis:  Extending that, the center cell is (I believe) the $3 \times 3$ sum, plus the sums of all four $2 \times 2$ rectangles, minus the sums of all four $3 \times 2$ rectangles.